# TYPO3 get products per uid out of backend

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm new to TYPO3 and Fluid. I want to generate a dynamic PDF through a button.

My problem is I don't know how to get my products with their uid.

[image: Folder]

[image: Products]

[image: Properties]

All of them have a uid. My question is how can I display them in my frontend using fluid code?

If I try to access the product data with cObject Records I get the error "Table doesnt exists"

So I figured out cObject uses the database thats why I get the "Table doesnt exist" error

But thats not what I want. I want to get the data out of the backend records.

TypoScript:

```
lib.fluidLoadRecord = RECORDS
lib.fluidLoadRecord {
  source.data = current:1
  source.intval = 1
  dontCheckPid = 1
  tables = product
}
```

Fluid:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.fluidLoadRecord', data: '69')}

<!--<v:page.resources.fal table="product" uid="69">
<pdf:text>{product.description}</pdf:text>
</v:page.resources.fal>-->
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure that the table is called `product` and not something like `tx_product_domain_model_item`. You can e.g. check the source code of the input field *ProductSeries*  and you will see something like that

```html
data-formengine-input-name="data[be_groups][1][title]"
```

In my example the table would be `be_groups`.

---

For the rendering you need some more code like this

```
lib.fluidLoadRecord = RECORDS
lib.fluidLoadRecord {
  source.data = current:1
  source.intval = 1
  dontCheckPid = 1
  tables = tx_your_db_table_name

  conf.tx_your_db_table_name = COA
  conf.tx_your_db_table_name {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      field = producseries
      htmlspecialchars = 1
      wrap = <h1>|</h1>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your answer! I've already found the solution. You were right. I tried to access it through the backend but thats simply not possible. The access must be through the database tables.
Should I answer my own question with the solution?

Comment: if you found a nice solution, yes please also add it

Comment: I added it. Can you help me with how to joining two tables and display them?

Answer (score 0):

So as already provided in this post here is the solution.
It is not possible to access data directly from the backend.
It is only possible through the database tables.

```
lib.fluidLoadRecord0 = RECORDS
lib.fluidLoadRecord0 {
source.data = current:1
source.intval = 1
dontCheckPid = 1
tables = tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_product

conf.tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_product = TEXT
conf.tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_product.field = producseries
}
```

And here how to use it with cObject

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.fluidLoadRecord0">69</f:cObject>
```

And if you want to join some tables and display them you can use something like that.

```
lib.productfamily = CONTENT
lib.productfamily {
table = tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_product
select {
  uidInList = 69
  pidInList = 369
  selectFields = title
  join = tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_productfamily on 
         tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_productfamily.cruser_id = 
         tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_product.cruser_id
  where = tx_bmyproducts_domain_model_product.uid
  }

 renderObj = TEXT
 renderObj {
 field = title
  }
 }
```

Then you can display the data with cObject.